Custom type formats in connexion
The documentation on how to how to implement custom type formats suggest doing something like this
import re
from jsonschema import draft4_format_checker

MONEY_RE = re.compile('^\$\s*\d+(\.\d\d)?')

@draft4_format_checker.checks('money')
def is_money(val):
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        return True
    return MONEY_RE.match(val)

But doing that results in the following error
DeprecationWarning: Accessing jsonschema.draft4_format_checker is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Instead, use the FORMAT_CHECKER attribute on the corresponding Validator.
I tried to solve it by doing like this instead
import re
from jsonschema import draft4_format_checker

MONEY_RE = re.compile('^\$\s*\d+(\.\d\d)?')

@Draft7Validator.FORMAT_CHECKER.checks('money')
def is_money(val):
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        return True
    return MONEY_RE.match(val)

This seems to be the wrong way of doing it since the custom type is not being validated at all.
What should I do to avoid the DeprecationWarningError?
